# AttributeError when initializing Flask app - 'MySQL' object has no attribute 'connection'

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to run a flask app together with a MySQL server. But I can't seem to get pass the connect-to-db stage. My `app.py` has the following code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)
mysql = MySQL()

app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST '] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'mypassword'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'users'
app.config['MYSQL_CURSORCLASS'] = 'DictCursor'
mysql.init_app(app)
cur = mysql.connection.cursor()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('layout.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When I run this script in `Git Bash`, I get:

```
$ python app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 13, in <module>
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
AttributeError: 'MySQL' object has no attribute 'connection'
```

I do not see any issue with the `app.py` script above. The `MySQL` module is imported, initialized and it still does not run. Can someone please offer some suggestions of what could possibly be the problem?

Comment: Try this: `from flask_mysqldb import MySQL` instead of `from flaskext.mysql import MySQL`... Or use your previous import and use the cursos as: `cur = mysql.get_db().cursor()`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should import this and then run your code :

```
import mysql
import mysql.connector
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the way you are getting the cursor to:

```
mysql.init_app(app)
cur = mysql.get_db().cursor()
```

Or use your previous code and change the import line to:

```
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
```

I hope it helps.